# No suitable user-defined conversion with overloaded constructors and inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance

Sorry to be the 1,000,000th asker of this kind of question!

I'm trying to put together some rudimentary vector classes using inheritance. Excuse dumping everything in .h, my implementation has them split up but I'm compacting them here for brevity.

Vector.h

```
class Vector{
public:
Vector operator+(const Vector& rhs) {
    assert(dimensions == rhs.getDimensions());
    Vector result(dimensions);
    for (char i = 0; i < dimensions; i++) {
        result[i] = values[i] + rhs[i];
    }
    return result;
}
double& operator[](int index) {
    //Asserts 0 <= index < dimensions and returns values[index]
}
protected:
    Vector(char dimensions) :
        dimensions(dimensions), values(dimensions)  {}
std::vector<double> values;
private:
    char dimensions;
};
```

Vector3.h

```
class Vector3 : public Vector {
public:
    Vector3(double X, double Y, double Z) :
        Vector(3),
        x(X), y(Y), z(Z) 
        {values[0] = x; values[1] = y; values[2] = z;}
double& x, y, z;
private:
    Vector3(const Vector& vec) :
        Vector3(vec[0], vec[1], vec[2]) {}

};
```

I'm pretty sure this is everything involved with the problem...

Here is where it goes wrong:

```
Vector3 myVector3A(1,2,3); //OK
Vector3 myVector3B(4,5,6); //OK
Vector3 myVector3C = myVector3A + myVector3B; //Error: No suitable user-defined conversion for Vector to Vector3
```

I'm somewhat new to inheritance, which may be painfully obvious. I've tried writing a new `operator+` in Vector3.h which defines a pointer to `Vector`, assigns it to `this`, then specifically invokes `Vector::operator+` on the `rhs Vector3`, but this doesn't cut it (heh). A similar question implied there was no way to construct a `Vector3` from a `Vector`, so I've tried adding this as a constructor, but this doesn't do it either, as well as feeling a bit wrong. I've also tried manually adding a copy-assignment operator for `Vector`, with similar results.

Where have I missed something?

Comment: It's better you show the code how you implemented `operator+`

Comment: Done, thanks for the suggestion and cleaning up the rest of the question.

Comment: *I'm trying to put together some rudimentary vector classes using inheritance* You shouldn't. It doesn't work for everybody else and it won't work for you.

Comment: What's the difference between the `x` (which is a dangling reference to the double parameter `X`), `y` (a double), and `z` (also a double) in `Vector3`, and the `values` vector in `Vector`?

Comment: There is no difference, its for compatibility with existing code that uses someVector3.x and someVector3[0] interchangeably, but I can see how this implementation doesn't work at all. I'm going to rewrite it using @n.m's suggestion.

Comment: "uses someVector3.x and someVector3[0] interchangeably". You should kill that code with fire

Comment: Truer words have never been spoken

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not be using inheritance here at all. Inheritance simply doesn't work with binary operators.

If you want a generic Vector to abstract over the number of dimensions, the right approach is to parameterise it, creating a *class template*.

```
template <size_t D>
class Vector {
   // your data and methods here, 
   // nothing is virtual
};

using Vector3 = Vector<3>;
```

Comment: This looks much more sensible. Many thanks for the idea!

Comment: +1 for not using inheritance. `Vector` has arbitrary elements, then `Vector3` is not a `Vector`. There should be a notion of "no-inheritance", it models a "is-not-a" relationship ;)

Answer (score 0):

**Vector3 myVector3C = myVector3A + myVector3B;**

In this line the user defined conversion constructor would be invoked (Vector -> Vector3).
**Vector3(const Vector& vec) :
        Vector3(vec[0], vec[1], vec[2]) {}**

But since this conversion constructor is private you are possibly getting the compiler error.
Please make it **public** and hopefully it'll be resolved.